# What does -h option mean in java command line?

Tags: bash, shell

During reading a bash script file, I see this:

```
java -cp ${CP} ${CLASS} -h redis > /dev/null 2>&1 &
```

Does anyone have any idea about "-h" and "redis"?

Running "java -h" seems to print the help info, but why would someone need to print help info when running a java program as a background process?

And for the "redis", I know it's a database in memory, I just don't know what does that mean to add it to the java command line. Does that mean java would first check if a process named "redis" exists?

Thank you!

Comment: It seems, that '-h redis' is a parameter to the main method of the Java program in ${CLASS}.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Any arguments that come after the class name will be arguments to that class' `main` static method; it is not an argument to Java. I.e., your `${CLASS}` will be called with `YourClass.main(new String[]{"-h", "redis"})`.

Comment: I checked the main method, seems that the args is never used, does that mean these 2 arguments "-h" and "redis" are actually useless?

Comment: I don't know, I did not see the code. If you are looking in the correct place, and if you haven't overlooked them being used, then yes, they would be useless.